# What is the current state of tail-call-optimization for F# on Mono (2.11)?

Tags: linux, f#, mono, arm, tail-call-optimization

What is the current state of Tail Call Optimization (TCO) implementation on Mono (2.11) ? Read somewhere that all the codebase would need to be modified to use a callee-pops-arguments convention. What is the status of this change ? Is the ARM/Linux port up to date on this matter ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you probably want to change the title of your question--F# in general works on Mono.  You're asking about one feature of F#--an important feature I grant but still just one part of F#.

Comment: I've got a parser combinator program that works on .NET and fails on Mono 2.10.8. Will try to test on 2.11 shortly

Answer (score 3):

Tail calls definitely work on mono on linux - tested using

```
let rec f a = f (a+1)
```

which didn't crash - tested on Mono 2.10.2

## UPDATE

Tested with link from Brian - https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=476785

which crashes on Mono 2.10.2 despite generating `.tail` instructions

Comment: The F# compiler converts direct recursion into a loop.  Use two mutually recursive functions to test.

Comment: @Brian - checked the dissasembly - you are correct, do you have a good example program which generates `.tail` instructions

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Try [this example](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=476785). I don't think it has been fixed in Mono 2.10.

Comment: I cant reproduce the bug guys.   2.10.2 is ancient, you know that right?   You want 2.10.8 at least.   About 10 months of work between those two releases

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza - just tested on mono compiled from git master which crashed when compiling the file using `fsc --optimize+ --tailcalls+` and with `mono --optimize=all` and just plain `mono`

Comment: Has the callee-pops-arguments convention already been implemented on the git master 2.11 ? I read it was the main reason holding back a correct implementation of tail instructions.